# Can't get file downloaded but only the webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to download a file using `urllib.request`:

```
import urllib.request   
urllib.request.urlretrieve ("urlusedtodownload", "fileoutput")
```

But sometimes I only get the webpage source, and not the file I want to download. Does anyone know what might be causing this? How can I ensure that I will always download the file?

Comment: This would be due to the website, yes. If you're requesting a direct URL for a file, you should (theoretically) always get the file, unless the website is doing something funky to block you from getting the file.

Comment: so what could be a suggestion for me to always get the file? is it possible to upload a file to a filesharing platform that doesn't change the url? how can I recognize that kind of platform?

Comment: What extension is the file? If the file always remains the same it could be best off to upload it to a direct source

Comment: what you mean for direct source? yeah the file is the same

Comment: are you using the url of the download page or the url of the actual file?